# Add enter in text on links in mermaid

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I would like to add an enter in the text when displaying text on links in mermaid. We could use `\n` to display an enter, but the text is split from each other. Here is some reproducible code:

```
flowchart LR
    A-- text\ntext -->B
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see there is a nice enter, but the text is split from each other and not nicely in one box. So I was wondering if anyone know how to enter text on links while having one box with text?